# Direct sum notation: $G = \bigoplus_{\alpha < \beta}\mathbb Zx_{\alpha}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, abelian-groups

I was reading the direct sum of the groups and the index notation looks little bit strange for me.

Group $G = \bigoplus_{\alpha < \beta}\mathbb Zx_{\alpha},$ where $\beta$ be an ordinal.  Is this group in the form $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \oplus ...,$ where the number of copies of $\mathbb Z$ is less than the cardinality of $\beta$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your interpretation seems good to me. I guess I wouldn't write it using $``\cdots''$, but it looks like you understand that the index set doesn't need to be countable. The $x_\alpha$ are probably just a convenient way to label the generators.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct . . . ish.

The $\alpha$ is not necessarily countable, so your use of "$\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z\dots$" is not strictly appropriate (not least because it does not include the $x_{\alpha}$).

This is what it really means: "the direct sum over all $\alpha<\beta$ of $\Bbb{Z}x_{\alpha}$".